# Question about HttpCookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cookies

I need to generate a cookie that has a secret value which I am the only one to know it . 
 
Ideas ?

**UPDATE**

I have a handler page which is available for everyone I call this page to get RSSFeed using Ajax . What I need to do is preventing other people from forging HttpRequest and get the data returned I've tried to use Authentication forms but no good also I heared about nonce token stuffs but I have no Idea how to use it . ! 

**UPDATE2**
[Read This](http://stackoverflow.mobi/question812945_ASP-NET-PageMethods-and-JQuery-AJAX-Post---How-secure-really-is-it--.aspx) this exactly my problem ..

Comment: Why do you want to send a secret value in a cookie?

Comment: your question not properly written. specify something to more what exact you want to do

Comment: Need additional info. How should the secret value be accessed? Only on server side or also in javascript? How long should the secret value be stored? As long as the page is opened or indefinitely (permanent cookie)? Why would you want / need a secret value in a cookie? Maybe there is some other solution. Please clarify!

Comment: Ah! So you don't need a cookie -> you need a token!

Comment: I suggest starting by reading this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html

Comment: I have a handler page which is available for everyone I call this page to get RSSFeed using Ajax . What I need to do is preventing other people from forging HttpRequest and get the data returned I've tried to use Authentication forms but no good also I heared about nonce token stuffs but I have no Idea how to use it . !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.mobi/question812945_ASP-NET-PageMethods-and-JQuery-AJAX-Post---How-secure-really-is-it--.aspx 
This is exactly my issue !!

Answer (score 1):

Generally storing sensitive information in a cookie is a bad idea, but you could encrypt it with a key that is only known to the server if the cookie isn't being used client-side. You can use the `AesManaged` class to encrypt it, and store the Key somewhere safe, such as a file with locked down ACLs.

Here is an example of how to do so.

```
public string GetEncryptedCookieValue(string cookieKey)
{
    using (var aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        aes.Key = new byte[0];//TODO: Replace this with getting the secret key.
        aes.IV = new byte[0];//TODO: Replace this with getting the secret IV.
        var cookie = Request.Cookies[cookieKey];
        var data = Convert.FromBase64String(cookie.Value);
        using (var transform = aes.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            var clearData = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clearData);
        }
    }
}

public void SetEncryptedCookieValue(string cookieKey, string value)
{
    using (var aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        aes.Key = new byte[0];//TODO: Replace this with getting the secret key.
        aes.IV = new byte[0];//TODO: Replace this with getting the secret IV.
        var clearData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        using (var transform = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            var data = transform.TransformFinalBlock(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
            Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie(cookieKey, Convert.ToBase64String(data)));
        }
    } 
}
```

Again, I would stress that storing sensitive information in a cookie is a practice that should be discouraged. If you update your question to what you are trying to accomplish, perhaps there is a more reasonable solution.